# function prints null value when printing a list?

Tags: python, printing, null

while messing around with an example from a book:

```
class Quick():
    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in vars(self).items())



class User(Quick):

    def __init__(self, first, last, location, gender):
        super().__init__()
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.location = location
        self.gender = gender
        self.loginattempt = 0

    def mmplusattempt(self):
        self.loginattempt += 1

    def mmresetattempt(self):
        self.loginattempt = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in vars(self).items())


class Admin(User):

    def __init__(self, first, last, location, gender):
        super().__init__(first, last, location, gender)
        self.privileges = ["delete post", "ban user", "shutdown server", "restart server"]

    def show(self):
        for p in self.privileges:
            print(f"This user can: {p}. \n")
        



admin = Admin("ADMIN", "ADMIN", "SERVER ROOM", "ADMIN")
print(admin.show())
```

this for some reason outputs :

```
This user can: delete post. 

This user can: ban user. 

This user can: shutdown server. 

This user can: restart server. 

None
```

I am not sure why it prints `None`. Changed `show()` to check for null value:

```
def show(self):
        for p in self.privileges:
            if p != None:
                print(f"This user can: {p}. \n")
```

still outputs `None`.

I thought maybe the loop wasn't working like I intended it to so added a null value in `self.privileges` to see if the loop was checking for null value correctly:
`self.privileges = ["delete post", "ban user", "shutdown server", None, "restart server"]`
output:

```
└─$ python3 classuser.py
This user can: delete post. 

This user can: ban user. 

This user can: shutdown server. 

This user can: restart server. 

None
```

Obviously the if test is working correctly. Where is this null value coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`show` function haven't return any value
if you return something in `show`, `None` will gone.

```
    def show(self):
        for p in self.privileges:
            print(f"This user can: {p}. \n")
        return "haha"
```

Comment: So a function will return `None` by default

Comment: Yes. [Doc](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#implicit-return-statements)